# How do I change IDEA's build folder from TEMP to something else?

Tags: java, applet

Im trying to run:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class img extends Applet
{
    private Image img;
    public void init()
    {
        img = null;
    }
    public void loadImage()
    {
        try
        {
            img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "winter.jpg");
            System.out.println(img);
            System.out.println(prepareImage(img, 300, 400, this));
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        System.out.println(getDocumentBase());
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if (img == null)
            loadImage();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't find winter.jpg unless its in: file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/

System.out.println(getDocumentBase()); returns:
file:/C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/AppletPage1228891259548967526.html
Instead of: 
C:/Users/Admin/Dropbox/dev/idea/Exam3/out/production/Exam3/ (where the .class files are located)

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.

I simply want to put my JPEGs in the Exam3 folder instead of the Temp folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for loading the resource using getDocumentBase() you can get the URL by using the getResource of class which gets the resources relative to the class.

```
URL base = img.class.getResource("/data/winter.jpg");
Image img = ImageIO.read(base);
```

where data is a folder in the Exam3 folder in your case which contains this class file.

Comment: very good. I prefer to keep resources in my src. To do that you can also do `this.getClass()` and apply `getResource` to that